# How to get the corresponding old record data in bulkBefore()?

Tags: apex, trigger

In my bulkBefore() method I have the following `for` loop

```
    for(SObject sObject : Trigger.new) {
       Account acc = (Account) sObject;
    }
```

to help me get all new account records.
For each account record I want to retrieve the same account but with the old data from Trigger.old

Please advise how to get for each account record its old record data?

Comment: ‘bulkBefore’ is not a standard method. Can you add more relevant code?

Comment: `Trigger.oldMap.values()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Trigger.oldMap` within the for loop to retrieve the old values:

```
for (Account acct : Trigger.new) {
    Account oldAcct = Trigger.oldMap.get(acct.Id);
    // Now you have new and old values for the same account record
}
```